# python mpi key error "duplicate_keysharedFilename[0]"

Tags: python, multithreading, mpi, multiprocess

I'm trying to write a simple python script based on mpi4py module. My script generates a file list and send each file to a different process by means scatter command. 
The invoked program will open, read and return content of each file.
But, when i run my script as "mpirun -np 4 python main.py /home/roberto/prog2.py"
I get the following error:

```
[cli_0]: Command cmd=put kvsname=kvs_19767_0 key=sharedFilename[0]    value=/dev/shm/mpich_shar_tmpZlYmCm
failed, reason='duplicate_keysharedFilename[0]'
Fatal error in PMPI_Init_thread: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(392).....: 
MPID_Init(139)............: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(38)........: 
MPID_nem_init(196)........: 
MPIDI_CH3I_Seg_commit(337): PMI_KVS_Put returned -1
```

Making some tests i've observed that it is attributable to the hdf5 library imported in prog2. It is compiled for MPI and conflicts with MPI invoked by mpi4py in the main script. If i remove it from imports, it works! Anyway, i need it in my script. Any suggestion? Is it possible to unlink hdf5 from MPI from inside script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with a mpi4py [MCVE] that simply `os.system(...)`

Comment: the easiest option is to make `prog2` a subroutine and call it directly from `main.py`. IIRC, you can build `hdf5` without MPI support (and you might have to rebuild python bindings too), that could fix the issue (but you might have to adjust `prog2.py`)

Comment: I builded hdf5 without MPI and now it works! Thank you @GillesGouaillardet!